# Overwrite contents of file with file descriptor

Tags: shell, sh, posix

How can I completely overwrite the contents of a file via a file descriptor?

There is already a question asking the exact same thing, but with no clear answer: [Bash, overwrite using file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068741/bash-overwrite-using-file-descriptor).

#### Example

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -e -x

echo "Hello world, this is a test." >&3

sleep 1

cat ./state

sleep 1

echo "Hello." >&3

sleep 1

cat ./state
```

parent.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -e -x

echo "" > ./state
exec 3> ./state

./script.sh
```

Running `parent.sh`, expected output:

```
+ echo ''
+ exec
+ ./script.sh
+ echo 'Hello world, this is a test.'
+ sleep 1
+ cat ./state
Hello world, this is a test.
+ sleep 1
+ echo Hello.
+ sleep 1
+ cat ./state
Hello.
```

Actual output:

```
+ echo ''
+ exec
+ ./script.sh
+ echo 'Hello world, this is a test.'
+ sleep 1
+ cat ./state
Hello world, this is a test.
+ sleep 1
+ echo Hello.
+ sleep 1
+ cat ./state
Hello world, this is a test.
Hello.
```

Comment: I thought the answer there was pretty good. What's unclear?

Comment: I don't need the explanation, rather a clean and simple workaround. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: The workaround is in the part starting with "*If you did want to open a new independent FD*" (see especially the last code snippet in the answer); i.e. use `/dev/fd/3`.

Comment: Yes but the workaround is rather messy and convoluted. Thought there is a cleaner way of dealing with this.

Comment: What's messy and convoluted about `echo "Hello." >/dev/fd/3`?

Comment: @melpomene I tried that but it did not work.

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to do this?  Like the linked question explains, the file remains open while file descriptors with write access are open.